# How to remove part of the string in powershell?

Tags: string, powershell

Here is a list of projects, around 300 lines. I want to cut off (ID: ...) from each line using PowerShell.

Currently, I have:

```
BlockService API (ID: Projects-1)
BlockService 1 (ID: Projects-903)
CheckService ScheduledJob (ID: Projects-620)
Checkout Archibus (ID: Projects-96)
BackOffice Service (ID: Projects-12)
```

And I need to get:

```
BlockService API
BlockService 1
CheckService ScheduledJob
Checkout Archibus
BackOffice Service
```

I/m not sure how to do with TrimStart and TrimEnd as I can't get desired results...any advice?

Comment: Please make it clearer what you expect the string to look like before and after modification, and post your existing attempts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace parts of string using regex in PowerShell:

```
$s = "BlockService API (ID: Projects-1)"
$s -replace "\(ID.*\)",""
```

or

```
"BlockService API (ID: Projects-1)" -replace "\(ID.*\)",""
```

Comment: Why is it when you add the `^` (i.e. marks the start of the string) and `$` (i.e. marks the end of the string) to your regular expression that it does **not** work anymore? For example, `"BlockService API (ID: Projects-1)" -replace "^\(ID.*\)$",""` does not work. Why is this?

Comment: To use ^ and $ you need to change the whole expression to ^.*\\(ID.*\\)$, so that the input strings match again. As you already mentioned ^ marks the beginning of a string but your input string doesn‘t start with (ID...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you would like to use `Trim` methods. If you have the projects in `projects.txt` text file, you could do with this instead:

```
Get-Content ".\projects.txt" | ForEach-Object {($_ -split " \(ID:")[0]}
```

Comment: Well, I tried various options but didn't found a solution. I didn't use PowerShell a lot in the past. This also is working for me, thanks!